# Let $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ and let $A_k = \{x \in \Bbb R^n : |f(x)| \ge k\}$ for $k \in \Bbb N$. Show that $\lim_{k\to \infty} k \cdot m(A_k)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be an integrable function and let $A_k = \{x \in \Bbb R^n : |f(x)| \ge k\}$ for $k \in \Bbb N$. Show that $$\lim_{k\to \infty} k \cdot m(A_k)=0.$$

I had few ideas for this, but not sure how to put them together. Since $A_k$'s form a decreasing sequence I have that $m(\bigcap_{k} A_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty} m(A_k)$. Also since $f$ is integrable I have that $\int_{\Bbb R^n} |f| < \infty$. Now in order for $\lim_{k\to \infty} k \cdot m(A_k)=0$ I suppose that I somehow need to show that $\lim_{k\to \infty}  m(A_k)=0$? Then it would need to be that $m(\bigcap_{k} A_k) = 0$, but this doesn't feel like its true? What approaches could be taken here?

Answer (score 1):

By monotone convergence,
$$\int_{A_k^c}|f|\,\mathrm dm=\int_{\Bbb R^n}|f|\,\mathbf1_{\{|f|\le k\}}\,\mathrm dm\:\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\:\int_{\Bbb R^n}|f|\,\mathrm dm<\infty,$$
equivalently
$$\int_{A_k}|f|\,\mathrm dm\:\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\:0.$$
The left-hand side is at least $k\cdot m(A_k)$.

Comment: How does the integral $\int_{A_k} |f| \ dm \to 0$?

Comment: @UniQGat: $\displaystyle\infty>\int_{\Bbb R^n}|f|\,\mathrm dm=\int_{A_k}|f|\,\mathrm dm+\int_{A_k^c}|f|\,\mathrm dm$.

The right-most integral converges to the left-most one.

Comment: Not sure I understand. So $\int_{A_k}|f|\,\mathrm dm+\int_{A_k^c}|f|\,\mathrm dm \to \int_{\Bbb R^n}|f|\,\mathrm dm$, but how does it imply that the integral converges to $0$?

Comment: @UniQGat: It is an equality there. The $\int_{A_k^c}$ integral converges to the full integral (over $\Bbb R^n$). This means that the remaining integral $\int_{A_k}$ converges to $0$ (because of the equality).

Answer (score 0):

For each $k,$ define $f_{k}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
by $f_{k}=1_{A_{k}}f$. Clearly, $f_{k}$ is measurable and $|f_{k}|\leq|f|$.
Note that $A_{1}\supseteq A_{2}\supseteq\ldots$ and $\cap_{k}A_{k}=\emptyset$
because $f$ is real-valued. Therefore, $f_{k}\rightarrow0$ pointwisely.
By Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, $\int|f_{k}|\rightarrow0$.
By direct calculation, $\int|f_{k}|=\int_{A_{k}}|f|\geq k\cdot m(A_{k})$.
Hence, $k\cdot m(A_{k})\rightarrow0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: How is $\cap_{k}A_{k}=\emptyset$? This would imply that $m(\cap_{k}A_{k}=\emptyset) = \lim_{k \to \infty} m(A_k) = 0$ which would result in $\lim_{k\to \infty} k \cdot m(A_k)=0$ without the need of integrals.

Comment: We prove that $\cap_{k}A_{k}=\emptyset$ by contradiction. Suppose
the contrary that $\cap_{k}A_{k}\neq\emptyset$, then we can choose an
$x\in\cap_{k}A_{k}$. It follows that $|f(x)|\geq k$ for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
which is impossible because $|f(x)|$ is a real number.

We also observe that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $x\notin\cap_{k}A_{k}\Rightarrow x\notin A_{k}$ for some $k$.
Hence, for any $n\geq k$, $x\notin A_{n}$ because $A_{1}\supseteq A_{2}\supseteq\ldots$.
This shows that $1_{A_{n}}(x)\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$
and hence $f_{n}\rightarrow0$ pointwisely.

Comment: Just knowing that $m(A_k)\rightarrow 0$ alone is not enough to infer that $k\cdot m(A_k)\rightarrow 0$ because $k\rightarrow \infty$. (We encounter an indeterminate form $\infty\cdot 0$.)